# Converting from Fourier transforms in terms of radian frequency ($\omega$) to normal frequency f (in Hz)?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Say I have a table of functions in time, and their corresponding Fourier transforms in the radian frequency domain:

[image]

How can I translate these Fourier transform expressions to the standard frequency domain, f, in Hz?

Is it as simple as replacing every instance of $\omega$ with $2 \pi f$?

I don't think it is, because say I have a function below that I want to take a Fourier transform of: $$ x(t) e^{\displaystyle{j \frac{2\pi n}{T}t}} = x(t) e^{\displaystyle{j 2\pi n ft}} $$

We can write this as:
$$
x(t) e^{\displaystyle{j n \omega_0 t}}
$$

The Fourier transform of this is a standard result: $X(\omega - n\omega_0)$.

But if I try to convert this to be in terms of $f$:
$$X(2\pi f - n2\pi f_0) = X(2\pi(f-nf_0))$$

However, if I do the same question now by using the fact  that:
$$X(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-j2\pi ft} \mathrm{d}t$$
I get that the Fourier transform is $X(f-nf_0)$

So, the two results are not the same, as far as I can see.

Have I made a mistake somewhere? Or is that not the way to convert between $f$ and $\omega$?

Answer (score 1):

In general,

$$F(\omega)\neq G(f)$$
For every $f_i$ there is an $\omega_i=2\pi f_i$ such that $F(\omega_i)=G(f_i) \rightarrow F(2\pi f_i)=G(f_i).$

I think your confusion comes from using the same letters for $F$and $G$.

This is where $X(2\pi(f-nf_0))=X(f-nf_0)$ comes from..

To "get the one from the other",
$$G(f)=F(2\pi f)$$
$$F(\omega)=G(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})$$

In you example,
$$G(f-nf_o)=F(2\pi(f-n f_o))$$